# How can I parse info from kotlin docs to swagger-ui?

Tags: kotlin, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I need to parse kotlin docs (not swagger annotation) for swagger-ui.

I tried [this](https://springdoc.org/#javadoc-support), but it don't work.

Here my springdoc dependencies (springdocVersion = "1.6.6"). By the way, I can't use therapi version 0.13.0 if it's important.

```
runtimeOnly("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:$springdocVersion")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:$springdocVersion")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:$springdocVersion")
implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-javadoc:$springdocVersion")
annotationProcessor("com.github.therapi:therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe:0.12.0")
implementation("com.github.therapi:therapi-runtime-javadoc:0.12.0")
```

Comment: The `therapi-runtime-javadoc` library used by `springdoc-openapi` only works with Java, not Kotlin. I believe it might be possible to develop a similar library for Kotlin using the [Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP) API](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html), but I haven't looked into it deeply. In any case, it might be worth filing an enhancement request in the [springdoc-openapi issue tracker](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I replaced `annotationProcessor("com.github.therapi:therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe:0.12.0")` with `kapt("com.github.therapi:therapi-runtime-javadoc-scribe:0.12.0")`, all worked well!

An example of the build file can be found [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1324)