# SpringDoc / OpenAPI: How do deal with JavaDoc vs. @Schema?

Tags: java, openapi, javadoc, springdoc

I'm working on a Spring Boot project which uses SpringDoc to generate an OpenAPI schema.

I'm struggling with the documentation because on the one hand this:

```java
/** Description of the class */
public class MyClass { ... }
```

... will be interpreted by the IDE (IntelliJ) as a doc comment, but the Java compiler doesn't preserve it, so it's gone at runtime so SpringDoc cannot read it. On the other hand, this:

```java
@Schema(description = "Description of the class")
public class MyClass { }
```

... will be interpreted by SpringDoc, but the IDE will not recognize it as a doc comment.

Duplicating the descriptions and having both clearly is also not ideal.

How does everybody else handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-javadoc', refer to the documentation https://springdoc.org/v1/#javadoc-support.
@Schema has a higher priority than javadoc, and the two can be used together.

Comment: Cool! In case anybody needs it, there's a variation that works for kotlin as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773537/3094906